# How to create image slide show with time interval in windows phone app?

Tags: image, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1, slider

I am developing windows phone app.In this I want to set image slider.like image moving form right to left sides with some time interval.I have tried lot of examples but all are  showing manually slide the image.but I want to slide the image automatically. please help me.

Answer (score 0):

I've once created such an image carousel with a timer.
The basis to get this done is available on this post http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/27766.windows-phone-how-to-create-a-simple-image-carousel-using-basic-windows-phone-controls.aspx

Only thing to get this triggered automatically, instead of using buttons like on the blog post, is by adding a timer to the page and on the tick event of the timer, trigger the storyboard animation.

So add a `DispatcherTimer _imageTimer = new DispatcherTimer();` on your page and in the constructorset the timing and what method to call

```
_imageTimer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2.5);
_imageTimer.Tick += OnTimerTick;
```

No in the method that get's called when the timer goes off trigger the animation.

```
private void OnTimerTick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   _scrollAnimation.From = 0;
   _scrollAnimation.To = 480;
   _scrollViewerStoryboard.Begin();
}
```